# Why can I list other users processes without root permission?

Tags: linux, security, process

Using `ps -aux` or `top`, I can list other users running processes, but I'm neither running as root nor making use of `sudo`, why?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

By default, you can always list other users processes in Linux.

To change that, you need to mount `proc` in `/etc/fstab` with `hidepid=2`:

```
proc            /proc           proc    defaults,hidepid=2
```

This functionality is supported from the kernel v3.2 onwards. It hides /proc and consequentially `ps` activity from all users except root.

Taken from [this article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-hide-processes-from-other-users/) about `hidepid`:

> *hidepid=2* - It means hidepid=1 plus all /proc/PID/ will be invisible
>   to other users. It compicates intruder's task of gathering info about
>   running processes, whether some daemon runs with elevated privileges,
>   whether another user runs some sensitive program, whether other users
>   run any program at all, etc.

Comment: This solve the part "being able to list other users running process", but don't understand why this is not this way by default since the beginning.

Comment: Because this breaks the Unix way and compatibility with some daemons.

Comment: It's just an old tradition that a timesharing system would be an open community.

Comment: If Mr. Bad Guy got to run programs on your system, it is game over anyway. This is just hiding stuff that is vital for normal functioning of the system. to give a cracker a bit of a nuisance. "Security theater" at it's most glorious.

Comment: I have been running a farm of servers like that, and actually your comment is giving me an idea for a good question. Will write it later on 3AM here, and it will take time to report my findings

Comment: If you run a process which can be an attack surface use containerization so it will have its own PID namespace alongside network, mount, user and UTS (hostname and NIS domain name) namespaces, cgroup and root file tree. So you will achieve much more and still won't break anything.

Comment: This should absolutely be the default. People should be able to see root-level processes, so this shouldn't break any daemons, to them the computer is identical to as if the other users didn't exist. This has nothing to security, but overwhelmingly privacy. Many workplaces and universities have multiuser systems, and with the Linux default you can easily see exactly what everyone else is doing. Unfortunately I don't think many people understand this, so while losing privacy is one thing, losing it without knowing its lost is another.